# How do I recover my vs code dev container after setting a dockerfile context and hitting 'Unable to resolve resource vscode-remote://...'

Tags: dockerfile, vscode-devcontainer

I have a project that uses VS Code dev containers, using Docker Desktop in Windows with WSL2 and roughly has the following structure in Ubuntu WSL2.

```
proj
|-.devcontainer
|  |-devcontainer.json
|  |-Dockerfile
|  |-requirements.txt
|-src
```

The devcontainer.json has the following:

```
{
  "build": {
    "dockerfile:": "./Dockerfile"
  },
  ...
}
```

Everything works fine.

One day I decided to try to move my requirements.txt to a subfolder outside of .devcontainer

```
proj
|-.devcontainer
|  |-devcontainer.json
|  |-Dockerfile
|-deps
|  |-requirements.txt
|-src
```

I change devcontainer.js to the following:

```
{
  "build": {
    "dockerfile:": "./Dockerfile",
    "context": "../deps"
  },
  ...
}
```

Doesn't work and fails to connect.  I revert my changes and it continues to fail with the same error.

```
Unable to resolve resource vscode-remote://dev-container%2B7b22686f737450617468223a225c5c5c5c77736c2e6c6f63616c686f73745c5c5562756e74755c5c686f6d655c5c6177656e675c5c64616d6c222c226c6f63616c446f636b6572223a66616c73652c22636f6e66696746696c65223a7b22246d6964223a312c2270617468223a222f686f6d652f6177656e672f64616d6c2f2e646576636f6e7461696e65722f646576636f6e7461696e65722e6a736f6e222c22736368656d65223a227673636f64652d66696c65486f7374227d7d@wsl%2Bubuntu/workspaces/proj
```

Re-installing VS Code, pruning Docker, re-installing Docker Desktop, pulling repo to a new folder all fails.  Debating paving the machine at this point...  And I just tried the same repro steps on a different machine and hit the exact same issue.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The error changed to Error opening dev container configurations: CodeExpectedError: ENOPRO: No file system provider found for resource 'vscode-remote://dev-container...

This was a bug introduced recently in vscode-devcontainer and either rolling back to v0.309.0 or forward to pre-release v0.317.0 resolves the issue.

[VS Code "Disconnected from Dev Container" - No file system provider found for resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77234168/vs-code-disconnected-from-dev-container-no-file-system-provider-found-for-re)

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/9060