# VS Code "Disconnected from Dev Container" - No file system provider found for resource

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use VS Code to open a directory in a dev container I immediately get a "Disconnected from Dev Container" message. Looking at the dev container log I see the following:

[22 ms] Dev Containers 0.315.0 in VS Code 1.83.0 (e7e037083ff4455cf320e344325dacb480062c3c).
[21 ms] Start: Run: wsl -d Ubuntu -e wslpath -u \wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\duane\mychan
[339 ms] Error opening dev container configurations: CodeExpectedError: ENOPRO: No file system provider found for resource 'vscode-remote://dev-container...

I'm running Windows 11 with WSL2. This seems to have started after I updated Ubuntu and then got a failed update of vscode. I've reinstalled VS Code, the remote dev extensions, and Docker Desktop. None of this helped. Note that I can successfully open the dev container from windows but not from WSL.

Comment: the latest pre-release version `v0.317.0` resolves this as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Downgrading the Dev Container extension to version v0.309.0 seems to 'resolve' the problem, as per this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/9060#issuecomment-1747811300

Comment: switching to the pre-release version `v0.317.0` works as well and resolves this issue.